# How to access badges in phone app?

Tags: support, badges

I can't find how to see the badge counts etc on the phone app. is it not an implemented feature or am I blind?

Comment: At the very least, it's possible to "click" the (blue) top bar in your profile while on your phone, which redirects you to a webpage, containing all the info you're looking for.

Comment: I think [mse] is better suited for this question (though I suspect it's been asked before)

Comment: @KyleKanos I'll have a look thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perusing [Meta.StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) leads me to [this question & answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257836/) from June 2015. The answers to the question both say the app isn't meant to be a replacement for the the main site, that

> the app is therefore optimised for this, allowing you to view, comment on, answer, vote and flag posts.

So the (current) answer is that you cannot see the badges you've earned on the site (unless it was a recent one that'd be in your Achievements list, but clicking on that would lead you to the mobile site).